# execute a C# method asynchronously using Threading in windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

i have a windows service that runs every 10 seconds to execute the read method. The Read method connects to remote server with the connection url provided in the constructor.
if the remote server fails to respond, it throws error and goes to catch. How do we make the thread to start again?

```
class PMTicketsService
{
    private Timer _serviceTimer;
    private TimerCallback _timerDelegate;

    public PMTicketsService()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Set the method to execute when the timer executes.
        _timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(Receive);

        // Create timer and attach our method delegate to it
        _serviceTimer = new Timer(_timerDelegate, null, 1000, 10000);
    }

    public void Receive(object state)
    {
        ABC abc = new ABC(Url);
        ABC abc1 = new ABC(Url1);

        /* Create the thread object, passing in the abc.Read() method
        via a ThreadStart delegate. This does not start the thread. */
        Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(abc.Read());
        Thread oThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(abc1.Read());

        // Start the thread
        oThread.Start();
        oThread1.Start();

        oThread.Join();
        oThread1.Join();
    }
}

class ABC
{
    public string strUrl;

    public ABC(string url)
    {
        strUrl = url;
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        try
        {
            // Code to use the connectionurl to access a remote server
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If the connection url fails to respond, how do we make thread start again?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code could use some cleanup...

Comment: @James. how do you check for the exceptions in threading and start another thread. do you have code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, you should submit sample code that actually compiles. I took what you had and cleaned it up, removed the unnecessary timer and structured it in a way that should give you what you need. In the code below, your Read  method will continue running until you set `done` to `true`.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ABC abc = new ABC("www.abc.com");

            // Create the thread object, passing in the abc.Read() method
            Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(abc.Read));

            // Start the thread
            oThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    public class ABC
    {
        string strUrl = "";

        public ABC(string url)
        {
            strUrl = url;
        }

        public void Read()
        {
            bool done = false;

            while (!done)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Code to use the connectionurl to access a remote server
                    //Use strUrl in here
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Wait 10 seconds before trying again
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                }

                //On success, set done to true
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to start another thread?  Starting/stopping threads is an expensive operation, you're far better off just keeping the existing thread open and continually trying to connect (possibly with a sleep in between).  You already have the try/catch to keep the thread from crashing.  Just wrap the try/catch in a while(!done) and set done to be true once you successfully connect.

You might also want to add some code so that if you can't connect X times in a row (maybe 5?) then you'll stop trying, or increase the timeout between connection attempts.

Comment: I just told you pretty well exactly what you need to do, and what you need to do has nothing to do with threading at all; all of the threading stuff is already done.  You need to define a boolean, add a while loop, and probably add a Thread.Sleep.  Those are the only lines of code that you need to add, and I've told you where you need to add them.  I have complete confidence in you that you can turn that into the source code without needing to just copy/paste it from someone here.